# Ad Mob Interstitial on CoronaSDK Show itself only one time

Tags: lua, admob, coronasdk

I've build a little `main.lua` to test the ads of admobs but I have a problem with my interstitial admob.

```
-- The name of the ad provider.
local provider = "admob"

-- Your application ID
local appID = "ca-app-pub-7171907831713303/2674724079"

-- Load Corona 'ads' library
local ads = require "ads"

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Setup ad provider
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Create a text object to display ad status
local statusText = display.newText( "", 0, 0, native.systemFontBold, 22 )
statusText:setTextColor( 255 )
 statusText:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
statusText.x, statusText.y = display.contentWidth * 0.5, 160

local showAd

 -- Set up ad listener.
 local function adListener( event )
-- event table includes:
--      event.provider
--      event.isError (e.g. true/false )

local msg = event.response

-- just a quick debug message to check what response we got from the library
print("Message received from the ads library: ", msg)

if event.isError then
    statusText:setTextColor( 255, 0, 0 )
    statusText.text = "Error Loading Ad"
    statusText.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5

    showAd( "banner" )
else
    statusText:setTextColor( 0, 255, 0 )
    statusText.text = "Successfully Loaded Ad"
    statusText.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5
end
   end

 -- Initialize the 'ads' library with the provider you wish to use.
if appID then
ads.init( provider, appID, adListener )
  end

  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 -- UI
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 -- initial variables
  local sysModel = system.getInfo("model")
  local sysEnv = system.getInfo("environment")

 -- create a background for the app
  local backgroundImg = display.newImageRect( "space.png", display.contentWidth,  display.contentHeight )
 backgroundImg:setReferencePoint( display.TopLeftReferencePoint )
  backgroundImg.x, backgroundImg.y = 0, 0
  statusText:toFront()

  -- Shows a specific type of ad
   showAd = function( adType )
local adX, adY = display.screenOriginX, display.screenOriginY
statusText.text = ""
ads.show( adType, { x=adX, y=adY } )
  end

 -- if on simulator, let user know they must build for device
 if sysEnv == "simulator" then
local font, size = native.systemFontBold, 22
local warningText = display.newText( "Please build for device or Xcode simulator     to test this sample.", 0, 0, 290, 300, font, size )
warningText:setTextColor( 255 )
warningText:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
warningText.x, warningText.y = display.contentWidth * 0.5, display.contentHeight * 0.5
else
-- start with banner ad
showAd( "interstitial" )
 end
```

I've tested this app on my devices and when I started it for the first time everything worked well. But after that no ads were shown. How long should I wait to see the ad?

What could be the problem?

Comment: I am having this problem too. Even after close it, i start a banner ad. The banner ad shows once and never show again.

Comment: Which plugin for admob are you using? there is admob-v1 and admob-v2 use v2 plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you call it only once. You need to call it in a loop with a delay or with any events occurring constantly.

You have to keep calling showAd( "interstitial" )